How can I write more efficient for loops in python
I want to print the first letter of each string in a list on one line, and then the next letter on the next line, etc. When a string runs out of letters, it prints a space instead. Also this is my first question on here, please let me know how to write better questions thank you so much and sorry if it's messy example from the course module: if
strings = ["abcqwe", "def", "ghiq"]

your program should print
adg
beh
cfi
q q
w
e

This is the code I was able to figure out without running into any errors, but I am 100% that is not the best way to do it lol, any tips on how to clean it up?
strings = ["abcqwe", "def", "ghiq"]
new_strings = []
big = 0

for string in strings:
    if len(string) > big:
        big = len(string)
for string in strings:    
    while len(string) < big:
        string += ' '
    new_strings.append(string)
for i in range(len(new_strings[0])):
    line = ''
    for string in new_strings:
        line += string[i]
    print(line)


Your first loop should be big = max(len(s) for s in strings).  And your last loop can be for parts in zip(new_strings): and print(''.join(parts)).

And just for the record, that's not a nested list.  It's a simple list of strings.

Wow, that seems like such an easy fix, but not one I ever would have thought of on my own! thanks for the help, I guess I just need to keep practicing

Python has a large standard library, which is what makes it so easy to use, but it means there are a lot of tools and functions to learn about.

And I will change the title of the question, thats a bit misleading! This was a bonus question in the module

@IanPak Use itertools.zip_longest with fillvalue=' ' instead.

@blhsing reading my mind... from itertools import zip_longest; print('\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in zip_longest(*strings, fillvalue=' ')))

@Ian See [ask]. SO needs a specific question which can be answered with facts and citations, rather than opinions. If you want to get a review, use Code Review.

You can do so:
for string in strings:

For every time you loop, the strings variable in your loop will change from the first abcqwe to the last ghiq.
But you just want the first letter so you write "[0]" to say that you want the first caracters of the string:
for string in strings:
  print(string[0])

And it will print:
agh

Now, we want the second letter on the second line so we add a loop to make all the carater:
for i in range(len(max(strings, key=len))):
    for string in strings:
        print(string[i], end="") #so no line return
    print() #we print a line for every first, second, etc list printed

we use max to return which is the longest string in the list and use the key "len" because len is used to determine the number of caracter in a string or the number of item in a list. if you use max without the key "len", it will return the last string of the list.
But now the ouput is:
adg
beh
cfi
qIndexError: string index out of range

There is an error because the second string in the list "def" has no 4 caracter (3 in python because we count 0) so it can't print. We need to print a space:
for i in range(len(max(strings, key=len))):
        for string in strings:
            try:
                print(string[i], end="") #so no line return
            except:
                print(" ", end="")
        print() #we print a line for every first, second, etc list printed

I use a try: except: because I say to python: if there is no error in the try code: run it, except there is an error: run this other code (leave a space.)
Final code:
strings = ["abcqwe", "def", "ghiq"]
for i in range(len(max(strings, key=len))):
        for string in strings:
                try:
                    print(string[i], end="") #so no line return
                except:
                    print(" ", end="")
            
        print() #we print a line for every first, second, etc list printed

Output:
adg
beh
cfi
q q
w  
e 

I'm sorry for my bad english.
Say it to me if I did an error.
